# Set image resolution via file_put_contents function

Tags: php, image-resizing

I am try to set resolution acutlly i am updating image content while image change so now i need change image resolution while image content update.what i have done i am showing below.
How can i do that with my code.

**Php**

```
$fname = "orderimages/firstName-".$_POST['getfirstname']."-";
 $finalfileb =$fname."/back_side.png";
  if((isset($_POST['back_imag_val'])) && (isset($_POST['getfirstname']))){

     //Get the base-64 string from data
       $filteredData=substr($_POST['back_imag_val'], strpos($_POST['back_imag_val'], ",")+1);
     //Decode the string
     $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);


    file_put_contents($finalfileb,$unencodedData);
      }
```

Comment: you should take a look at [the GD library functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/imagecopyresampled

Comment: @RTFM : Can you put this imagecopyresampled function on my code.If width is 200px and height also same.

Comment: @MarcB can you implement on my code.

Comment: We're not here to do your job for you. You need to try doing this yourself.

Comment: I am confused actuly i found these function already but totally confused.Please that is you kindness if you implement with my code.